# Circular Playing up in a Grid

Tags: list-manipulation, grid-layouts

As we know, there is a possibility to emphasize some elements of a `Grid` by highlighting its cell with `Background -> {Automatic, Automatic, {{i, i'}, {j, j'}} -> color}` , But how can we accentuate (for example a number or a symbol in a cell of a Grid) by a colored circle drawn on the number (symbol) of the cell.

```
list={{11,April},{12,Jun},{13,December},{14,November}}
gridlist = Grid[Transpose[list], Spacings -> {2, 2}, Frame -> {All},  FrameStyle -> {Red, Thickness[2.5]}, ItemStyle -> {Bold}]
```

I am going to play up `11, 12, 13 and 14` with circles drawn their environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gridlist2 = MapAt[Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[Yellow], Disk[],
      Style[Text[#, {0, 0}], 16, Bold]}, ImageSize -> 30] & /@ # &, gridlist, {{1, 1}}]
```

or

```
gridlist3 = gridlist;
gridlist3[[1, 1]] = (Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[Yellow], Disk[],
       Style[Text[#, {0, 0}], 16]}, ImageSize -> 30] & /@ gridlist3[[1, 1]]);

gridlist3
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this, E.g.:

```
ll = MapAt[Overlay[{#, Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}]}]}, ImageSize -> 30, 
    Alignment -> Center] &, list, {All, 1}];

gridlist = 
 Grid[Transpose[ll], Spacings -> {2, 2}, Frame -> {All}, 
  FrameStyle -> {Red, Thickness[2.5]}, ItemStyle -> {Bold}]
```

[image]

Adjust the mapping (or use replace, et. al) to highlight only those desired, e.g., `list[[{2, 4}, 1]] = ll[[{2, 4}]]` would replace just the second and fourth dates with circled ones...